Magento 2 : Class "Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController" not found
I use Magento 2.4.6-p5
Getting this error on compilation:
There is an error in htdocs/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/AddDatabase.php at line: 11
Class "Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController" not found#0 htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()

I removed the generated folder and cleared the cache, did not help. I also downloaded the setup folder from github for Magento 2.4.6-p5, gave me other errors. I also deleted the setup folder and ran composer install, but nothing composer said there is nothing to install or update.
Any ideas what else I can try?

@Saif
Hey,
If your custom module or any third-party module is using Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController, you need to update it to use Laminas equivalent classes.
For example, Replace:
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

With:
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

After making changes, make sure to update Composer's autoload files:
composer dump-autoload"
Thank You!

It's because you have legacy files in your setup folder, i.e. files from previous versions of Magento that are no longer on the last version.
You could try to FIRST delete your setup folder and THEN download it from github or (which I think should be the best practice) re-running composer install.
in my case running
 rm -rf vendor setup/ lib/ dev/ && composer install

resolved those errors.

This is the correct answer for this question.
Upgrading Magento does not remove the older files from the setup folder that's why this error is coming.

Please remove
rm -rf vendor/* generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* composer.lock setup/* dev/* lib/* 

and re-run
composer install


Did that, afterwards my setup folder was empty :-| ... what could be wrong? Lib folder was also empty afterwards. It finished normally though.

I was upgrading magento instance from earlier to latest.
When I am setup:di:compile this error keeps on throwing.
In my case No extensions were using the zend framework.
But the files inside the src/Magento/Setup/Controller were using it. Not one but multiple files using it.
You can use this to find the files using it.
grep -r "Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController" setup/

Solution
Compare the files in the magento repository, And remove the files inside src/Magento/Setup/Controller according to the repository.
It worked for me.
